# openlayers 3 - Load TileLayer with highest zoom level tiles but display at all zoom levels

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Is is possible to load a Tile layer from a TileImage source with tiles in its highest resolution (zoom) for a specific extent and have these tiles show for all zoom levels.  I have high resolution imagery I wish to show as a layer above another Tile layer such as Bing or OSM.

Example source

```
var source = new ol.source.TileImage({
projection: 'EPSG:900913',
tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
projection: 'EPSG:900913',
extent: projectionExtent,
//extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-83.7893967, 42.851353, -83.7855987, 42.849371], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:900913"),
resolutions: resolutions,
tileSize:[pictometryImageSize, pictometryImageSize]
}),
tileUrlFunction: function(tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection){
var zoom = tileCoord[0];

console.log(zoom)

if(zoom == 21){
    var tileGrid = this.getTileGrid();
    var center = ol.proj.transform(ol.extent.getCenter(tileGrid.getTileCoordExtent(tileCoord)),"EPSG:900913", "EPSG:4326");
    return 'www.myrealtileurl;
}
//return undefined;
//return 'https://dummy.com';
},
minZoom: 0,
maxZoom: 21
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you correctly. First, you can restrict layer extent with `extent`. Second, you can lock zoom with `maxZoom` and `minZoom` properties. OpenLayers will resize tiles on his own. Here is an example, where ArcGIS tile layer is locked in extent and zoom:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([-110, 42, -100, 48], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
          maxZoom: 6,
          minZoom: 6,
          url: 'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
          'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-105.89, 45.09]),
      zoom: 6
  })
});
```

Comment: I see this behavior if I use an XYZ source with the URL supplied.  When I try the same with a TileImage source, using the tileUrlFunction, the tiles for zoom 21 disappear when I zoom out to 20.  I assume that this is because the function is called for all zoom levels forcing me to return undefined for levels less than 21.

Comment: May be `ol.source.XYZ` will be good for you? It extends TileImage and has all functions including tileUrlFunction.

Comment: Tried that, no difference.  I noticed that if I return a bad url instead of undefined, the tiles are retained backwards for 1 zoom level before the disappear.  If I use the commented out extent, the tileUrlFunction stops being  called at zoom = 19.

Comment: Still not working as I expect, I am abandoning this approach to try an Image layer with an ImageCanvas source.  Thank you.